# Select product variations using buttons/swatches instead of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

In WooCommerce, by default interface, selecting product variations is possible through a  dropdown. But, I am developing a site where I wanted buttons/swatches instead of the dropdown.

I achieved that by assigning  radio buttons with  where I hide the  radio button's visibility and use  for styling it as a swatch button.

Everything is working fine. I use a function code in my functions.php to add  radio and an assigned  for each variation, and a JQuery to trigger the selection of variation in hidden  options when radio button is checked.

All I want is to know, if I can improve the JQuery that triggers this event. I want if a simpler JQuery can also achieve the same trigger function.

My code is

In functions.php

```
function wc_variation_buttons($html, $args) {
  $args = wp_parse_args(apply_filters('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', $args), array(
    'options'          => false,
    'attribute'        => false,
    'product'          => false,
    'selected'         => false,
    'name'             => '',
    'id'               => '',
    'class'            => '',
    'show_option_none' => __('Choose an option', 'woocommerce'),
  ));

  if(false === $args['selected'] && $args['attribute'] && $args['product'] instanceof WC_Product) {
    $selected_key     = 'attribute_'.sanitize_title($args['attribute']);
    $args['selected'] = isset($_REQUEST[$selected_key]) ? wc_clean(wp_unslash($_REQUEST[$selected_key])) : $args['product']->get_variation_default_attribute($args['attribute']);
  }

  $options               = $args['options'];
  $product               = $args['product'];
  $attribute             = $args['attribute'];
  $name                  = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_'.sanitize_title($attribute);
  $id                    = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title($attribute);
  $class                 = $args['class'];
  $show_option_none      = (bool)$args['show_option_none'];
  $show_option_none_text = $args['show_option_none'] ? $args['show_option_none'] : __('Choose an option', 'woocommerce');

  if(empty($options) && !empty($product) && !empty($attribute)) {
    $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
    $options    = $attributes[$attribute];
  }

  $radios = '<div class="variation-radios">';

  if(!empty($options)) {
    if($product && taxonomy_exists($attribute)) {
      $terms = wc_get_product_terms($product->get_id(), $attribute, array(
        'fields' => 'all',
      ));

      foreach($terms as $term) {
        if(in_array($term->slug, $options, true)) {
          $id = $name.'-'.$term->slug;
          $radios .= '<label for="'.esc_attr($id).'">'.esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name)).'</label><input type="radio" id="'.esc_attr($id).'" name="'.esc_attr($name).'" value="'.esc_attr($term->slug).'" '.checked(sanitize_title($args['selected']), $term->slug, false).'>';
        }
      }
    } else {
      foreach($options as $option) {
        $id = $name.'-'.$option;
        $checked    = sanitize_title($args['selected']) === $args['selected'] ? checked($args['selected'], sanitize_title($option), false) : checked($args['selected'], $option, false);
        $radios    .= '<label for="'.esc_attr($id).'">'.esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option)).'</label><input type="radio" id="'.esc_attr($id).'" name="'.esc_attr($name).'" value="'.esc_attr($option).'" id="'.sanitize_title($option).'" '.$checked.'>';
      }
    }
  }

  $radios .= '</div>';
    
  return $html.$radios;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'wc_variation_buttons', 20, 2 );
```

In JQuery (that I wish can be made simpler while achieving the same result as now)

```
$(document).on('change', '.variation-radios input', function() {
  $('.variation-radios input:checked').each(function(index, element) {
    var $el = $(element);
    var thisName = $el.attr('name');
    var thisVal  = $el.attr('value');
    $('select[name="'+thisName+'"]').val(thisVal).trigger('change');
  });
});
$(document).on('woocommerce_update_variation_values', function() {
  $('.variation-radios input').each(function(index, element) {
    var $el = $(element);
    var thisName = $el.attr('name');
    var thisVal  = $el.attr('value');
    $el.removeAttr('disabled');
    if($('select[name="'+thisName+'"] option[value="'+thisVal+'"]').is(':disabled')) {
      $el.prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code is for in user terms, rather than its mechanism.  Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: Great. Would help others too.